# glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred however culprit feature is numeric

Tags: r, regression, logistic, linear-model, separation

I've been receiving the warning message in the title and have reviewed posts such as e.g. [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11109/how-to-deal-with-perfect-separation-in-logistic-regression).

I would like to understand how this feature has perfect separation with the target variable, since I just assumed that this kind of warning would be more associated with categorical features, where one particular level has all of either true or false target class.

The context is website conversion (transaction makes a purchase True = X1 or not = False X0). I wanted to understand the impact of average page load time for a given website session. After removing other features like device type and traffic source, I have found that I only receive the warning with the feature Avg_Load_Time which is a numeric (dbl) feature.

My next thought was that maybe all those sessions with 0 avg load time were causing perfect separation however I have no zeros, just some close to 0:

```
> summary(x$Avg_Load_Time)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   0.24    2.32    4.27   10.18    8.73  484.62
```

I then looked at a summary of Avg Load Time only for those sessions with a transaction, where target is thus X1:

```
> summary(y %>% filter(target == "X1") %>% select(Avg_Load_Time))
 Avg_Load_Time   
 Min.   : 0.780  
 1st Qu.: 2.478  
 Median : 3.785  
 Mean   : 4.253  
 3rd Qu.: 4.815  
 Max.   :16.410
```

I can see here that while the min is higher, it's not 0.

How can I find the cause of my perfect separation given I've narrowed it down to a single feature?

Here is a sample of 1000 if it helps. Any tips on understanding my separation appreciated:

```
dput(x %>% sample_n(1000))
structure(list(target = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("X0", "X1"), class = "factor"), Avg_Load_Time = c(0.77, 
39.1, 5.34, 5.45, 1.74, 2.18, 9.19, 4.73, 9.37, 2.45, 4.33, 1.86, 
1.93, 4.32, 18.13, 6.93, 3.57, 13.93, 130.38, 4.47, 26.67, 14.48, 
19.54, 9.41, 6.51, 3.78, 1.91, 2.98, 5.47, 2.24, 3.07, 27.9, 
8.8, 65.66, 10.23, 3.32, 1.81, 5.02, 2.71, 1.04, 11.76, 5.73, 
2.32, 3.54, 2.3, 63.9, 4.5, 0.78, 1.44, 4.06, 0.7, 1.79, 7.7, 
4.3, 33.25, 1.44, 0.79, 6.39, 4.17, 0.6, 3.58, 16.84, 11.07, 
16.05, 28.29, 9.22, 4.1, 7.81, 0.55, 64.88, 3.32, 10.44, 3.22, 
1.57, 1.01, 7.16, 3.41, 5.74, 3.73, 2.62, 4.39, 17.92, 5.05, 
1.94, 6.95, 1.86, 27.07, 7.69, 4.05, 2.96, 8.03, 3.21, 5.33, 
1.62, 17.03, 8.37, 1.7, 5.08, 4.96, 0.83, 4.65, 16.36, 7.04, 
4.9, 22.98, 6.08, 4.3, 2.91, 1.52, 1.81, 11.28, 16.71, 4.17, 
9.62, 3.18, 2.66, 0.78, 9.3, 25.39, 5.84, 1.13, 58.03, 1.45, 
10.45, 19.5, 1.25, 1.06, 30.49, 2.9, 7.31, 3.61, 4.64, 0.68, 
10.43, 8.84, 1.78, 17.16, 6.68, 4.61, 7.43, 5.03, 2.98, 2.89, 
4.15, 9.47, 3.68, 2.16, 2.09, 41.78, 3.06, 113.4, 30.13, 5.37, 
14.83, 2.1, 2.03, 13.51, 3.1, 5.54, 4.61, 18.09, 23.82, 34.64, 
4.99, 8.35, 7.45, 3.98, 3.44, 1.01, 34.45, 64.03, 2.82, 13.63, 
13.34, 0.66, 4.15, 2.06, 19.7, 1.38, 2.16, 10.65, 5.89, 57.27, 
17.51, 3.5, 10.97, 2.2, 9.38, 2.06, 5.25, 4.11, 72.22, 0.93, 
3.65, 5.71, 4.79, 3.01, 0.95, 6.6, 15.35, 1.05, 3.31, 3.44, 8.31, 
11.35, 6.63, 4.87, 4.83, 10.05, 1.01, 25.35, 3.79, 11.14, 24.26, 
9.71, 1.76, 3.75, 1.66, 7.02, 6.41, 3.72, 3.58, 35.16, 3.24, 
2.29, 9.61, 9.31, 0.67, 0.63, 7.08, 10.85, 2.65, 4.35, 5.86, 
3.24, 4.32, 3.34, 2.37, 4.23, 1.97, 1.83, 15.42, 4.17, 5.18, 
2.37, 8.91, 0.71, 20.18, 5.96, 1.41, 3.11, 26.85, 2.47, 5.99, 
2.53, 1.86, 2.67, 13.66, 8.28, 5.7, 8.1, 3.95, 139.35, 15.37, 
2.55, 2.85, 5.46, 2.55, 17.16, 2.87, 23.42, 1.58, 62.58, 7.5, 
14.41, 1.57, 4.42, 5.41, 4.62, 12.5, 3.3, 4.37, 3.91, 3.35, 7.27, 
1.11, 24.86, 18, 8.83, 7.87, 2.68, 2.77, 32.58, 12.66, 2.64, 
9.89, 30.86, 10.17, 3.49, 37.99, 4.99, 12.98, 1.75, 11.92, 45.36, 
3.35, 2.28, 2.83, 19.92, 9.33, 4.98, 19.76, 2.92, 3.84, 4.8, 
205.98, 4.53, 8.82, 3.74, 21.8, 3.56, 3.9, 2.29, 7.85, 79.96, 
3.56, 2.78, 5.9, 2.93, 3.76, 1.79, 12.94, 2.34, 25.17, 22.71, 
4.15, 6.87, 147.62, 6.1, 3.23, 93.41, 12.91, 4.93, 3.22, 5.84, 
8.73, 17.73, 79.63, 182.45, 2.36, 1.62, 1.22, 1.09, 3.75, 0.93, 
1.82, 12.14, 4.38, 2.1, 0.88, 4.36, 1.33, 3.74, 2.85, 2.34, 13.2, 
5.44, 9.94, 6.6, 2.79, 7.7, 10.99, 11.43, 19.7, 3.79, 2.26, 1.68, 
23.24, 7.41, 3.13, 5.22, 2.4, 4.48, 2.35, 10.36, 1.25, 34.14, 
7.37, 3.46, 18.84, 8.32, 4.9, 2.37, 1.03, 4.56, 9.7, 20.95, 1.01, 
17.42, 9.29, 0.88, 3.84, 13.82, 0.52, 4.51, 11.74, 1, 6.28, 5.49, 
6.13, 5.62, 0.53, 6.72, 2.08, 3.38, 68.72, 4.56, 2.45, 15.21, 
5.54, 5.13, 3.86, 4.89, 1.21, 3.88, 4.83, 4.97, 8.22, 5.76, 4.07, 
6.83, 1.94, 120.71, 3.26, 7.38, 4.21, 5.95, 3.7, 1.28, 3.43, 
1.42, 1.63, 3.97, 10.57, 8.98, 2.37, 21.73, 8.04, 5.18, 2.48, 
5.74, 4.65, 1.85, 6.75, 0.98, 1.72, 4, 6.08, 7.21, 8, 10.98, 
1.94, 0.75, 30.3, 7.29, 3.31, 4.3, 66.62, 3.87, 3.01, 1.56, 3.37, 
5.44, 6.76, 6.21, 1.39, 8.02, 2.95, 9.56, 1.62, 2.28, 0.46, 2, 
12.55, 4.66, 15.48, 1.76, 5.81, 1.94, 4.25, 2.65, 1.51, 2.7, 
27.43, 46.24, 2.67, 16.77, 0.7, 0.4, 6.07, 11.3, 1.49, 3.45, 
3.2, 22.74, 1.5, 0.7, 2.6, 7.89, 2.57, 3.42, 2.46, 1.7, 2.45, 
2.12, 7.97, 9.4, 3.58, 7.2, 12.18, 15.27, 2.94, 5.19, 7.33, 7.54, 
5.01, 5.08, 10.65, 16.13, 2.46, 5.28, 3.02, 2.82, 10.84, 0.53, 
4.22, 3.51, 10.69, 4.31, 2.55, 7.58, 19.3, 4.97, 9.39, 1.66, 
0.45, 2.71, 0.82, 0.7, 8.76, 21.98, 1.95, 1.09, 3.78, 2.71, 2.55, 
1.69, 17.2, 6.37, 11.42, 2.33, 0.98, 52.6, 1.67, 1.32, 21.99, 
34.11, 4.99, 4.52, 6.84, 2.45, 0.7, 1.16, 9.52, 21.73, 2.32, 
5.26, 7.34, 3.55, 2.6, 4.29, 9.48, 0.48, 7.22, 1.94, 4.25, 6.62, 
6.76, 3.39, 1.67, 3.81, 38.39, 3.49, 65.29, 3.59, 11.54, 1.87, 
4.21, 6.6, 7.3, 8.97, 9.82, 2.65, 4.99, 2.03, 4.81, 3.08, 6.41, 
1.29, 1.04, 3.53, 1.29, 4.07, 2.92, 2.91, 3.82, 4.94, 2.25, 10.05, 
8.87, 1.51, 3.26, 3.4, 0.68, 7.64, 0.6, 0.78, 6.25, 2.89, 17.56, 
4.83, 5.55, 9.6, 3.31, 2.43, 6.96, 5.05, 5.95, 6.96, 15.06, 45.99, 
1.74, 3.48, 1.83, 2.76, 6.35, 24.95, 1.96, 2.23, 2.23, 17.25, 
5.2, 12.57, 11.58, 10.85, 2.91, 1.1, 3.2, 6.4, 3.15, 5.55, 1.72, 
2.34, 1.83, 49.76, 1.87, 5.72, 3.59, 0.81, 8.8, 6.76, 2.06, 3.15, 
9.06, 15.15, 1.64, 4.92, 9.64, 3.7, 1.78, 1.88, 3.98, 4.93, 3.37, 
10.57, 4.41, 4.67, 6.39, 3.51, 21.83, 2.33, 0.68, 1.66, 2.89, 
4.57, 360.7, 5.89, 6.63, 8.59, 0.48, 8.08, 2.01, 1.59, 12.45, 
0.99, 2.3, 2.79, 1.47, 2.78, 2.05, 3.12, 17.84, 185.53, 3.71, 
0.8, 1.82, 12.42, 31.16, 2.27, 19.23, 1.48, 7.22, 0.24, 11.73, 
1.25, 14.06, 11.55, 1.48, 1.73, 5.01, 1.66, 2.25, 3.26, 6.73, 
4.66, 1.8, 5.25, 8.15, 3.94, 2.72, 1.69, 25.96, 4.46, 1.51, 1.61, 
1.67, 2.16, 5.24, 22.86, 3.64, 10.68, 4.65, 0.62, 0.64, 7.69, 
3.63, 37.52, 9.98, 3.27, 10.94, 1.92, 2.4, 1.04, 6.05, 5.34, 
3.4, 4.08, 72.08, 3.95, 5.1, 1.44, 17.06, 2.14, 4.17, 3.39, 7.79, 
5.71, 19.87, 2.54, 2.49, 3.44, 3.85, 12.06, 12.18, 1.7, 3.12, 
17.3, 4.41, 4.4, 0.82, 57.91, 124.91, 5.35, 5.41, 20.75, 13.54, 
0.82, 0.84, 8.62, 10.04, 1.08, 10.49, 7.05, 2.72, 1.18, 2.05, 
6.87, 3.51, 20.66, 4.69, 31.9, 4.64, 6.04, 1.71, 6.91, 70.11, 
2.83, 9.88, 2, 10.48, 4.25, 12.24, 1.27, 50.22, 0.85, 3.51, 5.47, 
0.69, 1.45, 2.97, 1.58, 2.2, 6.79, 15.88, 3.52, 1.75, 18.68, 
3.81, 2.87, 4.06, 69.44, 91.15, 0.79, 1.15, 6.57, 1.18, 4.33, 
7.3, 42.46, 40.83, 6.48, 32.34, 3.16, 41.11, 4.61, 1.57, 2.22, 
1.2, 2.35, 10.48, 6.82, 5.38, 5.51, 3.34, 57.3, 51.9, 10.52, 
1.85, 3.37, 4.42, 1.09, 29.53, 1.76, 2.48, 2.54, 10.22, 11.62, 
59.79, 176.17, 7.18, 4.36, 1.76, 7.34, 4.55, 8.21, 3.94, 9.64, 
1.62, 19.5, 5.53, 5.28, 1.59, 43.85, 24.02, 5.95, 6.34, 4.54, 
3.71, 1.48, 9.18, 5.56, 6.08, 15.67, 24.48, 0.8, 12.53, 4.14, 
29.11, 19.85, 2.54, 92.42, 44.65, 8.07, 2.44, 3.93, 3.79, 13.65, 
17.64, 3.67, 9.42, 3.43, 1.81, 11.76, 1.63, 4.27, 5.87, 11.66, 
3.77, 1.62, 3.58, 15.66, 4.46, 8.12, 7.35, 8.62, 6.24, 4.28, 
1.68, 3.93, 3.27, 2.67, 2.93, 161.22, 3.54, 2.62, 40.6, 1.09, 
2.3, 9.57, 1.1, 3.33, 17.41, 7.63, 4.01, 16.9, 3.8, 2.8, 3.56, 
2.51, 6.26, 1.84, 2.98, 4.92, 2.12, 6.35, 11.74, 2.64, 14.35, 
452.01, 1.7, 1.91, 4.79, 2.49, 7.61, 1.54, 8.19, 7.95, 2.81, 
7.08, 9.06, 5.17, 2.08, 7.92, 4.39, 22.12, 3.42, 3.82, 3.17, 
17.41, 3.29, 10.66, 31.54, 3.62, 26.38, 3.43, 10.32, 1.32, 10.71, 
2.75, 0.95)), row.names = c(6184L, 2551L, 2196L, 1039L, 2202L, 
2513L, 6486L, 916L, 4414L, 2131L, 4485L, 48L, 4451L, 428L, 82L, 
2537L, 3385L, 862L, 1963L, 4647L, 5071L, 2291L, 2995L, 3809L, 
2285L, 1515L, 327L, 3483L, 65L, 3061L, 3869L, 3477L, 3101L, 2373L, 
2719L, 3135L, 4565L, 1753L, 3063L, 6430L, 6003L, 2311L, 4421L, 
1644L, 4624L, 3624L, 5539L, 5660L, 6346L, 2726L, 1827L, 4540L, 
1783L, 6390L, 3L, 5930L, 4033L, 389L, 4441L, 4337L, 5426L, 4693L, 
1528L, 1651L, 1031L, 6197L, 1658L, 1607L, 3984L, 169L, 5577L, 
3275L, 4969L, 2540L, 4156L, 6473L, 5848L, 3533L, 3060L, 3899L, 
1891L, 4948L, 6339L, 3585L, 720L, 4000L, 1086L, 145L, 1657L, 
3040L, 3259L, 201L, 6284L, 40L, 4519L, 3823L, 3223L, 5009L, 5800L, 
5318L, 6275L, 1786L, 2839L, 6337L, 1608L, 209L, 5153L, 6367L, 
4579L, 354L, 4555L, 5648L, 4864L, 5039L, 1677L, 6116L, 5098L, 
1642L, 4770L, 2200L, 6191L, 3071L, 450L, 3636L, 4081L, 2510L, 
5294L, 1727L, 2803L, 2432L, 1601L, 3750L, 1342L, 1631L, 4963L, 
5250L, 1706L, 4321L, 2363L, 5493L, 1785L, 1871L, 4915L, 3863L, 
2609L, 3569L, 5090L, 6215L, 776L, 5994L, 3678L, 2258L, 2520L, 
5860L, 4978L, 571L, 1565L, 4433L, 2162L, 4047L, 4313L, 6357L, 
4122L, 5517L, 6401L, 709L, 2926L, 3962L, 5218L, 3417L, 4282L, 
6511L, 4401L, 308L, 6254L, 2895L, 1322L, 3314L, 1255L, 3496L, 
2530L, 1512L, 2848L, 4397L, 6493L, 4089L, 2933L, 3121L, 5843L, 
4478L, 2383L, 799L, 3954L, 1881L, 6246L, 6538L, 5655L, 3924L, 
6358L, 598L, 6321L, 2812L, 1495L, 2279L, 1566L, 1571L, 3243L, 
3463L, 3446L, 4494L, 5554L, 2408L, 3205L, 1415L, 503L, 4475L, 
2991L, 6206L, 3917L, 3783L, 579L, 4765L, 5490L, 2332L, 3855L, 
334L, 279L, 4344L, 2040L, 3374L, 5118L, 5522L, 943L, 1384L, 4601L, 
4265L, 1661L, 4688L, 4689L, 4901L, 5189L, 3486L, 5768L, 2838L, 
1224L, 5894L, 797L, 64L, 5550L, 71L, 4872L, 3641L, 4625L, 3234L, 
4074L, 4193L, 4694L, 4910L, 6064L, 711L, 5573L, 2679L, 435L, 
3532L, 1943L, 5559L, 3315L, 3558L, 1329L, 3639L, 1315L, 3333L, 
1385L, 969L, 4171L, 4913L, 6416L, 3509L, 1493L, 3441L, 4746L, 
5616L, 4951L, 3169L, 4749L, 831L, 2960L, 1296L, 16L, 2343L, 1135L, 
3011L, 1561L, 2271L, 6274L, 174L, 3444L, 6017L, 3905L, 2256L, 
6176L, 2010L, 4810L, 390L, 1249L, 2519L, 5377L, 6018L, 5639L, 
5085L, 2620L, 5812L, 4687L, 1585L, 1728L, 2769L, 3270L, 4024L, 
4315L, 423L, 1338L, 2607L, 4817L, 2097L, 870L, 6315L, 904L, 2440L, 
4453L, 361L, 57L, 499L, 592L, 261L, 2635L, 2813L, 529L, 2855L, 
5575L, 2611L, 577L, 2758L, 4659L, 3844L, 460L, 5323L, 1192L, 
2380L, 272L, 381L, 4215L, 1872L, 5269L, 4364L, 897L, 5692L, 147L, 
1357L, 5217L, 5735L, 300L, 6237L, 2495L, 105L, 446L, 2340L, 998L, 
4142L, 612L, 6281L, 1582L, 1222L, 1890L, 166L, 1640L, 5590L, 
58L, 3018L, 142L, 3891L, 3186L, 4745L, 299L, 4523L, 5641L, 784L, 
1204L, 1686L, 1584L, 3400L, 2020L, 1845L, 1339L, 2362L, 3775L, 
4993L, 3140L, 6136L, 3744L, 3660L, 4153L, 2724L, 2882L, 606L, 
4553L, 2163L, 1866L, 6542L, 3836L, 439L, 1593L, 4147L, 1863L, 
1478L, 1836L, 5330L, 2317L, 6407L, 4020L, 6340L, 5530L, 4834L, 
4014L, 5586L, 6277L, 1131L, 4902L, 1407L, 5960L, 6548L, 5643L, 
4351L, 905L, 4831L, 1502L, 619L, 4279L, 6394L, 128L, 2750L, 933L, 
2526L, 4238L, 3399L, 659L, 1480L, 2368L, 2682L, 5147L, 6000L, 
416L, 1817L, 5850L, 2734L, 4140L, 6131L, 6076L, 5482L, 5680L, 
2259L, 2351L, 4757L, 4151L, 289L, 859L, 5292L, 5635L, 1138L, 
3254L, 798L, 2505L, 4556L, 1551L, 3940L, 4871L, 5242L, 418L, 
6498L, 260L, 5817L, 4388L, 4007L, 3834L, 5505L, 5628L, 6338L, 
761L, 5450L, 5683L, 285L, 6111L, 5526L, 3037L, 4L, 2593L, 3748L, 
1503L, 4305L, 3995L, 2808L, 5340L, 723L, 5026L, 3815L, 780L, 
5079L, 4068L, 819L, 5578L, 5309L, 5343L, 4748L, 5907L, 6230L, 
750L, 4398L, 1132L, 608L, 6299L, 42L, 5876L, 3563L, 2357L, 4928L, 
4651L, 3820L, 6556L, 2657L, 1072L, 6177L, 5854L, 1055L, 3019L, 
3226L, 1947L, 2649L, 2658L, 3980L, 4411L, 4809L, 5374L, 6171L, 
2297L, 4886L, 1136L, 3304L, 5831L, 6033L, 3996L, 5566L, 2274L, 
5844L, 4357L, 4184L, 3931L, 1742L, 1906L, 584L, 1180L, 5983L, 
2034L, 3948L, 2299L, 1073L, 4888L, 2482L, 5282L, 1443L, 2127L, 
4934L, 4823L, 5775L, 1885L, 1196L, 148L, 6078L, 6388L, 6283L, 
6387L, 4507L, 2845L, 6058L, 3802L, 6417L, 6221L, 2099L, 5433L, 
2409L, 4856L, 4206L, 6222L, 2927L, 2702L, 456L, 4939L, 4571L, 
5468L, 5040L, 2424L, 5272L, 6453L, 5051L, 4724L, 5896L, 2916L, 
1310L, 5210L, 5510L, 646L, 5657L, 814L, 6170L, 676L, 6462L, 5444L, 
1140L, 5464L, 5277L, 845L, 4103L, 6037L, 3394L, 5133L, 4308L, 
6330L, 3808L, 3992L, 5485L, 3267L, 2779L, 1673L, 3759L, 540L, 
63L, 3328L, 5014L, 6502L, 1702L, 183L, 2793L, 1387L, 1509L, 1104L, 
6117L, 2521L, 1616L, 1915L, 5086L, 2052L, 980L, 1808L, 3238L, 
1065L, 3380L, 5700L, 627L, 5914L, 2915L, 3048L, 3623L, 1123L, 
6095L, 1816L, 5820L, 4345L, 834L, 4729L, 4228L, 4196L, 4470L, 
1279L, 5591L, 1570L, 2116L, 4849L, 4395L, 226L, 476L, 1626L, 
5747L, 3529L, 2431L, 1781L, 6031L, 2284L, 3319L, 1572L, 258L, 
3268L, 3450L, 1602L, 6434L, 5241L, 3211L, 1457L, 973L, 5836L, 
4221L, 5546L, 511L, 1494L, 4660L, 4740L, 6022L, 3065L, 4671L, 
1235L, 4859L, 5285L, 6085L, 1835L, 246L, 3957L, 2888L, 6273L, 
4354L, 6334L, 1819L, 5608L, 5737L, 2086L, 1058L, 2646L, 816L, 
4892L, 962L, 6487L, 2038L, 4419L, 5027L, 1894L, 3495L, 587L, 
3206L, 2829L, 4782L, 3643L, 1092L, 4123L, 5749L, 2676L, 2893L, 
3014L, 38L, 1912L, 5211L, 2243L, 4058L, 1213L, 2605L, 2442L, 
1232L, 5918L, 4185L, 3302L, 1337L, 6362L, 5555L, 307L, 2301L, 
2233L, 937L, 3907L, 5225L, 5638L, 975L, 2251L, 1050L, 1491L, 
6382L, 5216L, 2451L, 5973L, 5968L, 5662L, 502L, 5915L, 2422L, 
4802L, 3790L, 3299L, 2436L, 2277L, 2446L, 1261L, 6100L, 3587L, 
2741L, 1789L, 3988L, 2954L, 673L, 5694L, 2920L, 3473L, 578L, 
5383L, 3635L, 2474L, 4929L, 2527L, 2379L, 2749L, 2919L, 4747L, 
1568L, 2770L, 3580L, 4304L, 5181L, 463L, 3725L, 3582L, 6360L, 
3340L, 3527L, 2487L, 5010L, 4628L, 3698L, 3776L, 1653L, 1242L, 
755L, 6249L, 4548L, 4715L, 2907L, 3603L, 5111L, 3679L, 4719L, 
5415L, 3942L, 3701L, 5062L, 6464L, 3886L, 4970L, 5863L, 4053L, 
3203L, 2152L, 5063L, 558L, 4078L, 1168L, 3739L, 1542L, 3839L, 
3160L, 6303L, 2109L, 1773L, 5431L, 2239L, 4065L, 4771L, 6126L, 
478L, 1101L, 4449L, 889L, 1234L, 2784L, 1710L, 453L, 1939L, 4598L, 
5976L, 3052L, 2723L, 1453L, 144L, 1011L, 347L, 2381L, 5726L, 
1098L, 3801L, 2205L, 5924L, 5627L, 4158L, 1323L, 2716L, 6020L, 
5811L, 2453L, 2576L, 1343L, 1320L, 599L, 4175L, 2525L, 4167L, 
728L, 2376L, 3965L, 5238L, 3838L, 5333L, 6010L, 3692L, 6235L, 
1547L, 6061L, 4914L, 523L, 6040L, 3971L, 5140L, 470L, 6180L, 
5213L, 1000L, 5703L, 464L, 17L, 2573L, 2548L, 4077L, 6232L, 4488L, 
4627L, 2826L, 5015L, 4984L, 1940L, 6304L, 1287L, 4968L, 4008L, 
4960L, 6471L, 3094L, 2265L, 3780L, 5842L, 1355L, 4387L, 1961L, 
3508L, 5247L, 1715L, 4510L, 2579L, 5276L, 1884L, 2056L, 572L, 
4258L, 5438L, 3359L, 4644L, 2303L, 322L, 5600L, 688L, 569L, 1143L, 
4504L, 1109L, 2366L, 2628L, 513L, 6001L, 3407L, 5020L, 1613L, 
5690L, 5180L, 4863L, 2050L, 2599L, 2516L, 3648L, 2714L, 4472L, 
5454L, 2338L, 3966L, 903L, 1241L, 2971L, 4947L, 4792L, 3717L, 
3221L, 5182L, 1006L, 6137L, 2480L, 1403L, 3797L, 5872L, 4249L, 
195L, 6063L, 1898L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit:
Here's the full code I'm suing to runt he model:

```
library(caret)
## custom evaluation metric function
my_summary  <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL){
  a1 <- defaultSummary(data, lev, model)
  b1 <- twoClassSummary(data, lev, model)
  c1 <- prSummary(data, lev, model)
  out <- c(a1, b1, c1)
  out}

## tuning & parameters
set.seed(123)
train_control <- trainControl(
  method = "cv",
  number = 5,
  savePredictions = TRUE,
  verboseIter = TRUE,
  classProbs = TRUE,
  summaryFunction = my_summary
)

linear_model = train(
  x = select(training_data, Avg_Load_Time),
  y = target,
  trControl = train_control,
  method = "glm", # logistic regression
  family = "binomial",
  metric = "AUC"
)
```

After running this, I get the warning message.

Comment: What is the full model you are fitting?  Is it interacting with any other variables?  Also, how do you know it's this feature causing the problem?

Comment: @Glen I have added this to the post now.

Comment: Do you get the error if you fit the entire data set without the CV/training? Looks like highly imbalanced classes and I wonder if some folds have only 1 or even 0 in the smaller class. Have you tried stratifying the selection of folds by class to ensure that each fold has enough of the smaller class?

Comment: @EdM "Have you tried stratifying the selection of folds by class to ensure that each fold has enough of the smaller class" - How would I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I looked at your data and it is extremely skewed with outliers.  Thus you do not have perfect separation but the warning is occurring because some of the extreme observations have predicted probabilities indistinguishable from 1.

If you fit the model on the log of avg_load_time you will not get the error (I tested this on your sample data).

This answer explains what's going on well: [Issue with complete separation in logistic regression (in R)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336424/issue-with-complete-separation-in-logistic-regression-in-r)

Comment: hours of manually outliers treatment saved for this answer. Thanks.